# Can I edit the “Release Date” field of podcasts in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, metadata

My [workaround for iTunes automatically assigning hollow star ratings to new podcast episodes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7805/how-do-i-stop-itunes-from-automatically-assigning-a-hollow-star-rating-to-podcast/13864#13864) has an unfortunate side-effect: after dragging the podcast files back into iTunes, they not longer have their “Release Date” field populated, meaning they can’t be sorted in release date order. (Which gives my tiny little mind the heebie-jeebies.)

I can figure out what the release date was for these podcasts, but iTunes won’t let me amend this field via the UI.

Is there *any* way I can edit the value of this field?

Comment: [This discussion on Apple Support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2114802?start=0&tstart=0) suggested that adding a `RELEASEDATE` extended attribute to the MP3 file with the release date as the value might restore the value in iTunes. I tried it with MP3TAG on Windows, but unfortunately it didn’t seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell, the answer is a resounding “no” — at least without deleting your iTunes Library .itl file.

Answer (score 1):

There's an application called ID3 Editor that will allow you to restore the release data info for podcast files.

Comment: Can you add a link to the application's website?